What's the correct Lewis structure representation for a fluorine atom?
Working on:

Richard Post, Chad Snyder, Clifford C. Houk. (2020). Chemistry: Concepts and Problems, A Self-Teaching Guide, 3rd Edition (p. 93)

In this book, I have the following exercise appearing in Self-test section:

My question is:
Isn't $\ce{F}$ supposed to have one more electron represented as a dot on the left side in this formation equation?

Yes, it is supposed to. What more would you like to know?

You know, while this site in principle is for all "levels of knowledge", I would really appreciate less very trivial questions.

Thank you for your response, @Mithoron. Since that's a screenshot from a chemistry book, it's understandable that someone with less experience might be confused if the publisher overlooked it.

I'm not sure if the Lewis structure for an arbitrary element is considered very trivial for someone just starting out with chemistry, but you probably know better. My first two questions were downvoted, even though I didn't post 'do my homework' type of questions and used the proper mchem package to format the elements. My last question seems to align with what I read in the Help Center: 'You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems you face.' Is there something I might be overlooking? I'll appreciate your advice.

Ummm... what does that little ‾ mean, at the top right of the structure?

This question here is pretty much of "am I right" type. If the answer is "yes, you are" then what are we even supposed to tell you more, besides not to ask q. like that? You can try chat, though. Either main room, or a new one.

BTW by very trivial I meant very basic, or low level of experience with chemistry. I think most of such new q. is either already covered in multiple old ones, or not really useful to keep on site.

@DrMoishePippik negative charge?

@Mithoron, please don't give away the answer for HW. ;-)
